# Android Studio 2.2 NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have some problem with my NDK project. I have one file.cpp and into a few functions, for example:

```
path_to_method_NameMethod1();
path_to_method_NameMethod2();
```

If I use the declaration

```
extern "C"
```

before method

```
path_to_method_NameMethod1();
```

I can run the application and call native methods from Java, but if I use

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL path_to_method_NameMethod1
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String
task.mndk.and.mndkproject.MainActivity.stringFromJNI()
(tried Java_task_mndk_and_mndkproject_MainActivity_stringFromJNI
 and Java_task_mndk_and_mndkproject_MainActivity_stringFromJNI__)
```

What do I not do right? Why do I need to use

```
extern C
```

in a .cpp file?